# How to detect the height of a view?

Tags: android, view, height

I have 2 layouts:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addhere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**a.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to inflate a.xml layout and add it to the view group with id **addhere** and then detect the height of a's view. `a.getHeight()` gives me 0.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View a = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.a,null);
        ViewGroup b = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.addhere);
        b.addView(a);
        Log.d("states", a.getHeight() + ""); // show me 0

    }
```

Please tell me how I can detect the height of a's view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        Log.d("states", "a's height: " + v.getHeight());
        a.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the view tree is still not measured and laid out at the time `onCreate()` is called.

If api < 11 use `view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()`

else use `view.addOnLayoutChangeListener()`.

Remember to remove listener in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
final View view=a;
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @TargetApi(16)
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else
            {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            final int width=view.getWidth();
            final int height=view.getHeight();
        }
    });
```